# How do I synchronize cache list access

Tags: java, multithreading, caching, synchronization, locking

I've got the following problem (one important restriction - cannot use external jar/libraries, only java primitives that come with regular install):

Objects of class X are stored long term in sql DB. Objects are cached for performance sake (needs to be written. Intend to base it on LinkedHashMap).

`get(key)`:
check if object is in cache and not in use - return it.
    if object is in use - sleep till it's available.
    if object is not in cache - read it from DB.

`putInCache(object)`:
update object in cache (if it's not there, add it).
    if the cache is exhausted it will trigger a `saveToDB` operation by the cache and remove 
    from cache the least recent used item.

`saveToDB(object)`:
write object to DB (not removed from cache) and mark object and "not changed".

There are multiple threads calling `get`. A thread can change the object it received from `get` (and the object will be marked as "changed") - when it's finished it will call `putInCache`.

There is one dedicated thread that goes over the cache objects and when it encounters a "changed" object it will trigger `saveToDB` (object will be marked as used while DB access is going on).

How would you recommend to ensure thread safety ? 
Basically I'm looking for the right Java classes that will enable:
1. `get` to synchronize it's access to each object in the cache. So that it can check if it's there and if so - if it's used or free for grabbing. If it's used - it should sleep until it's available.
2. the dedicated thread should not lock the cache while calling `saveToDB` but still making sure all the cache is examined and no starvation is caused (the cache might change while `saveToDB` is running)

just to clarify I'm only interested in the locking/synchronization solutions - things like the cache triggering and DB access can be assumed as given.

Comment: I would start with using `synchronized`, you don't appear to need to hold this lock to perform saveToDB. You can use the lock to `wait()` when the key you want is in use.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: please can you elaborate more? do you mean to wrap all functions with synchronize? how will it solve my problems? I'm new to java so i might be missing basic and obvious stuff...

Comment: When you wrap all your methods with synchronized, they all implicitly share a lock and thus your cache can only be access by one thread at a time.  This means if you can avoid wrapping any methods that might be a good idea, esp if any of those methods access the network or any thing very slow. ;) Later you can look at more complex locking/thread safety strategies, but I would master using synchronized first.

Comment: I perceive synchronized as a huge mutex (coming from C world). I don't want to use it - specifically in the "dedicated thread" since it will take some time to save to the DB all the changed objects. That's why i'm looking for a more tailored approach.

Comment: Maybe so but at least it Just Works(tm). Start by making your code work with it and then use finer grained locking.

Comment: Ok. I get the drift. If no other answer will be given I'll use synchronized...

Comment: I have given a sketch for an approach; maybe you'll be interested... More details on demand

Comment: @DrorCohen There are many other answers as I suggest, all of them more complicated.  Until you are completely comfortable with synchronized, I would try them just yet.  `synchronized` costs as little as 0.1 micro-seconds.  You are right that you don't want to be holding a lock while you access a database, which is why I suggested you not do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach:

- use an `ExecutorService` to handle DB requests;
- use `Future`s for your map values;
- use a `ConcurrentHashMap` as a map implementation.

The `Future` should get from the DB; it will use the `ExecutorService`.

When you need to make manipulations on one object, synchronize on this future's `.get()` which will be the object.

Also, google for "Java concurrency in practice", and buy the book ;)

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I'll go read about the classes you mentioned. And I do have a book which I'm reading while posting ("Programming Concurrency on the JVM").

Comment: Note: when I mean `Future` I really mean `FutureTask` here. It implements both `Future` and `Callable`.